# How do I remove core files in Unix?

Tags: unix, makefile

I need to add to my makefile a clean command that removes core files that might be produced from my program. My program hasn't ever produced any core files but I need to add it in the makefile anyways.

I saw somewhere that i could do rm core but I just keep getting an core doesnt exist as a file or directory error.

```
example: example.c
        gcc -o example example.c
clean:
        -rm $(objects)  example
```

Answer (score 4):

If the core file is named `core`, then just do `rm -f core`.

The `-f` option tells `rm` not to complain if the file doesn't exist. (It also tells it to go ahead and remove it without a prompt even if it's not writable.)

In a `Makefile`, you can have:

```
clean:
        -rm -f $(objects)  example core
```

Note that some systems give core files names other than just `core`. `man 5 core` for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get feedback if the file is removed you could also do the following:

```
# Clean core files only if they exists
clean:
    -rm -f $(objects)  example
    [ -e core ] && rm -v core
```

Its basically just a normal bash command, but if you don't care about knowing if its been deleted then Keith's answer is best :)